# set new image source permanently

Tags: javascript, image, replace, src

I'm trying to randomly replace images in a grid. The new images flash briefly (in Chrome) every time the function is triggered, but then the old images reappear. I know there's a very simple explanation for why I'm having this problem, but of course, I can't figure it out. Any help at all will be appreciated.

The site in question is http://www.apocwords.net/systems/randomdungeon.html. If you click on the words Randomize Me!, the blocks in the top, left, right and bottom sides should switch to the new, randomly selected images.

```
function createMe() { 
document.getElementById("left2").src = xLefts[Math.floor(Math.random()* xLefts.length)];
document.getElementById("left3").src = xLefts[Math.floor(Math.random()* xLefts.length)];
document.getElementById("left4").src = xLefts[Math.floor(Math.random()* xLefts.length)];
}

The HTML:
<img src="/images/templates/template_left_05.jpg" width="100" height="200" id="left2" class="template"/>
<img src="/images/templates/template_left_01.jpg" width="100" height="200" id="left3" class="template"/>
<img src="/images/templates/template_left_02.jpg" width="100" height="200" id="left4" class="template"/>
```

I'm sure there are a million ways to do what I'm trying to do better, faster and more efficiently. But, I don't care about that right now. I just want to know why what I'm trying to do isn't working.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a "href" attribute in your link. When you click it, you make a new request for the same page. You can either:

1. Remove it and use [this css property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) on the link, to make the "hand" pointer.
2. use [this jQuery method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 0):

change the Randomize Link to...

```
<a href="javascript:createMe(); return false;">Randomize Me!</a>
```